# Change select statement in SQL from Excel - end user

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have a decent size SQL statement that I have connected to an Excel worksheet and it runs fine.  The question I have is would it be possible to have the end user enter a list of values in an excel sheet or somewhere else and have those values added to a WHERE clause in my SQL to limit the results per the users needs without the user having to go into connection and alter the SQL etc.?  Thank you.

Comment: Exactly how is your SQL "connected" to the worksheet?

Comment: Data - > Connections > From SQL Server and then pasted into the properties.  Is there a better way to do this that would allow user input that could alter a WHERE clause? This is the only way I have learned thus far to connect and enable auto update.

Comment: Try recording a macro while seeting up the connection, then see if you can edit that.  Post back with your VBA if you run into problems.

Comment: We don't have enough info. are you trying to filter based on a single column, multiple columns, are you trying to do an `IN()` function (where it only returns results where column value is in the list. or a not in, or greater then less then. If you just want a small amount of filters like a date or a single value, you would be best to use paramters you could [Have a Look at this Article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/customize-a-parameter-query-HP010216113.aspx) to get you started it covers the basics. This is the best method as you don't actual have to write any VBA.

Comment: I am wanting to use IN() based on one column - the report right now returns all values (in this case articles) but different parts of the business only want to see their relevant articles. Will have a look at this article - thanks much

Comment: So I have the SQL statement in the definition and the parameters are not available for editing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I do it as part of a VB script. I'm not a VB expert and I didn't set it up- I just know enough to tweak some changes that the users require.

Conceptually- provide an area in th Excel template for users to enter the parameters, use VB to get the values of those parameters, then pass them to the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Data Connection in Excel that utilizes a parameter.  Whether you are calling a Stored Procedure on the DB or sending raw SQL, you can replace part of the statement with a ?.  Tie that parameter to a specific cell.  Now all your user needs to do is enter/change the value in that cell and it will re-query the database using that value as the parameter.

(I don't have Excel in front of me, otherwise I'd walk you through the exact steps)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I have a connection in Excel but I haven't figured out how to do so with a parameter - I can put the SQL in either as the full query or a stored proc not sure which is better